# Color is not changed correctly after state change

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

So I'm trying to do a simple app that changes the color to red or green and goes back to black if a price fluctuates, my currently implementation is this

```
@Composable
fun LaunchingComposable() {
 var coinPrice by remember {
        mutableStateOf(2000.30)
    }  

CoinHeader(modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 8.dp),
                        "http://myicon.com/image.png",
                        coinPrice
                    )
                    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                        delay(3000)
                        coinPrice = 2000.40
                        delay(3000)
                        coinPrice = 2000.20
                        delay(3000)
                        coinPrice = 2000.10
                        delay(3000)
                        coinPrice = 2000.20
                    }
}
```

...

```
@Composable
fun CoinHeader(modifier: Modifier, coinImageUrl: String, currentPrice: Double) {
    val baseColor = remember { Animatable(Black) }
    val previousPrice = remember {
        currentPrice
    }

        Row(
        modifier = modifier,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        AsyncImage(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(30.dp)
                .height(30.dp)
                .padding(end = 4.dp)
                .data(coinImageUrl)
                .build()
          
        )

        LaunchedEffect(currentPrice) {
            if (previousPrice < currentPrice) {
                baseColor.animateTo(Red, animationSpec = tween(1000))
            } else {
                baseColor.animateTo(Green, animationSpec = tween(1000))
            }
            baseColor.animateTo(Black, animationSpec = tween(1000))
        }
        Text(text = currentPrice.toPrice(), color = baseColor.targetValue)
    }
}
```

In my last composable I'm expecting the values to change to **Green - Red - Red - Green**

I need to always store previous value of my coinPrice in order to compare it, do a fade animation with the color and then come back to the black color.

Currently this is my output

[image]

### The problems are 2

- Fade in - out color from red to black or green to black not happening
- Seems like it always compare with the first value

Can anyone explain to me why if I recompose after coinPrice has been changed, the value of previous is not set correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current implementation of `previousPrice` is really just original price because it is never changed. You never set it to a new value, so it forever holds the first `currentPrice` ever received. Your `remember` call doesn't even have a key, so it will never recompute it, but even if you did, there would be no way to compute it to be the previous value instead of the current one.

I think you will have to use a mutable wrapper class around the remembered previous price so you can actually change it. An array may suffice, or you could write a specific data class to wrap a `var`.

Something like this:

```
val rememberedPreviousPrice = remember { arrayOf(currentPrice) }
val previousPrice = rememberedPreviousPrice[0]
rememberedPreviousPrice[0] = currentPrice
```

---

Secondly, you're using `baseColor.targetValue` instead of `baseColor.value`, so it's not using the animated value, but jumping right to the final ("target") color.

There could be other problems in your code. I'm not sure because I haven't done much with LaunchedEffects or animations in Compose yet myself.

---

By the way, you should not use Double for currency. Use BigDecimal instead. Read [here](https://dzone.com/articles/never-use-float-and-double-for-monetary-calculatio) and [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/228584/why-is-bigdecimal-the-best-data-type-for-currency).

Comment: This is interesting ! Thanks a lot for the answer, it did work correctly, now, I'm a little confused about state, because , as the LaunchedEffect launches new triggers of CoinHeader with a new currentPrice value, why the remember is not changed on the array type ? Because if I get rid of the array and just use remember { currentPrice } it won't work, this is what it confuses me of the recomposition

Comment: Also, I did not used big decimal because this is a crypto currency app, I need every decimal and cannot be rounded

Comment: `remember` isn't the same as State. The actual higher order function `remember` is called every time this recomposes. The first time it's called in this place in the composition, it returns the result of the lambda Every subsequent time, it returns the same remembered value. It doesn't matter that you happened to assign the result to a `var` and changed that `var` to point to something else later in your Composable. It can't know because it's not a property delegate--it's just a function you're calling. `remember` doesn't know or care what you're doing to the value after it returns it to you.

Comment: To use State, you would use `remember { mutableStateOf(currentPrice) }`. But the problem with using state for this instead of some "not-smart" mutable class like Array, is that the above code would trigger a recomposition so it would run twice and your `previousPrice` would always end up being the same as your `currentPrice` by the time you use it later in this composable. You could maybe move that third line down to the bottom of your function and that would maybe work (not sure as I'm not experienced with Compose yet), but the extra recompositions would be wasteful.

Comment: The fact that it cannot be rounded is precisely why you must use BigDecimal. BigDecimal is lossless for rational numbers in base 10. Double is stored in binary and it also has finite precision, so it will necessarily introduce rounding. See the second link in my answer above. [Try running this to see.](https://pl.kotl.in/gwRMak_dD) It's rounding toward the nearest rational binary number that fits in Double's precision, and then rounding that to the nearest decimal number before displaying it, so it introduces error.